# show create table, specifying the engine keyword

Tags: mysql

My production database is MySql 5.1.66. My development version is 5.5.28. When I run the statement `show create table` in production, the table DDL script outputs using the keyword TYPE to denote the storage engine. But that keyword was deprecated and replaced by ENGINE a while ago, so I can't create the table in version 5.5 without modifying the script output by version 5.1. Is there some sort of parameter to `show create table` that will cause the output to use the ENGINE keyword instead of TYPE?

Example output from 5.1:

```
CREATE TABLE `acr` (
  `IncidentNum` varchar(25)
) TYPE=InnoDB;
```

What it needs to run in 5.5:

```
CREATE TABLE `acr` (
  `IncidentNum` varchar(25)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `no_table_options` value in mysqldump's [`--compatible`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible) argument:

> - [`--compatible=name`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible)
>
>   Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or with older MySQL servers. The value of name can be `ansi`, `mysql323`, `mysql40`, `postgresql`, `oracle`, `mssql`, `db2`, `maxdb`, `no_key_options`, `no_table_options`, or `no_field_options`. To use several values, separate them by commas. These values have the same meaning as the corresponding options for setting the server SQL mode. See [Section 5.1.7, “Server SQL Modes”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html).
>
>   This option does not guarantee compatibility with other servers. It only enables those SQL mode values that are currently available for making dump output more compatible. For example, [`--compatible=oracle`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible) does not map data types to Oracle types or use Oracle comment syntax.
>
>   *This option requires a server version of 4.1.0 or higher.* With older servers, it does nothing.

As documented under [Server SQL modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html):

> #### Full List of SQL Modes
>
> The following list describes all supported modes:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - [`NO_TABLE_OPTIONS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_table_options)
>
>   Do not print MySQL-specific table options (such as `ENGINE`) in the output of [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-create-table.html). This mode is used by [**mysqldump**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html) in portability mode.